# AdMob Legacy Publisher ID not showing ads

Tags: ios, admob

My iOS "AdMob Legacy Publisher ID" not showing ads, started yesterday and not getting any ads today.  I tried using the new "Ad unit ID" and it works.

This sucks because now all my apps in the app store are not showing ads.

Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo=0xa28ff90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Yes I've it on my android app, sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this response from Google AdMob

> Hello,
>
> Thanks for contacting AdMob support.
>
> Our engineers have fixed this issue. Ads should now be serving
>   correctly. Your reporting should return to normal within 24 hours.
>
> Thanks for your patience,
>
> The Google AdMob Team

Looks like all is good now...On Aug 8th and 9th they had the problem, but for the past 5 days it has been stable.  Check out this fill rate...been >99% for the past five days.  [image: Check out this fill rate]