# Admob bannerView Request Error: No ad to show

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I'm having this issue on one of my ads for an ios game

Here is my code, the odd thing is that if I add the device on the request.testDevices list it displays the demo banner, if I remove from testDevices, it does not show a real banner, but if I change my bundleIdentifier on XCODE, it shows a real banner,so I believe its something with my admob account, does anyone ever got something like it?

Its always failing with this error:

AdView didFailToReceiveAdWithError --------------------------- : Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}

On my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    [FIRApp configure];
    [[FIRAnalyticsConfiguration sharedInstance] setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:YES];
    // Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK
    [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-xx~xx"];
    /* other stuff here... */

}
```

on my rootViewController.m

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    bannerViewAdded = NO;
    interstitialViewAdded = NO;

   [self addBanner];
   // ..... more stuff here;
 }

- (void)addBanner{

    NSLog(@"CALL ADD BANNER ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER");

    if(!bannerViewAdded && ![MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kFeatureAId]){

    NSLog(@"ADD BANNER ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER");
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];


    // Create adMob ad View (note the use of various macros to detect device)
    if (IS_IPAD || IS_IPADHD) {
        bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeLeaderboard];
        bannerView.center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, (size.height-CGRectGetHeight(bannerView.frame)/2)-2);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE6) {
        bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
        bannerView.center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, (size.height-CGRectGetHeight(bannerView.frame)/2)-2);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE6P) {
        bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
        bannerView.center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, (size.height-CGRectGetHeight(bannerView.frame)/2)-2);
    }
    else {
        // boring old iPhones and iPod touches
        bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
        bannerView.center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, (size.height-CGRectGetHeight(bannerView.frame)/2)-2);
    }

    //[bannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    // Need to set this to no since we're creating this custom view.
    //bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
    // before compiling.

    // Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xx/xx";
    bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];


    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    //request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    //request.testDevices = @[  @"xx", @"xx"  , kGADSimulatorID ];

    [bannerView loadRequest:request];
    bannerViewAdded = YES;
    }

}

- (void)removeBanner {
  //admob
  if(bannerViewAdded){
      bannerViewAdded = NO;
      [bannerView removeFromSuperview];
      [bannerView release];
      bannerView = nil;
  }
  //No AdMOB
  if(localBannerAdded){
      localBannerAdded = NO;
      [localBannerButton removeFromSuperview];
      [localBannerButton release];
      localBannerButton = nil;
  }
}


- (void)addInterstitial{

    if(!interstitialViewAdded && ![MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kFeatureAId]){
        NSLog(@"INIT INTERSTITIAL ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER");
        interstitialView =  [[GADInterstitial  alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-xx/xx"];

        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        // Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
        // an ad request is made. GADBannerView automatically returns test ads when running on a
        // simulator.
        //request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID, @"xxx", @"xxx" ];
        [interstitialView loadRequest:request];
        [interstitialView setDelegate:self];

    }

}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)gadBannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{
    NSLog(@"AdView didFailToReceiveAdWithError --------------------------- : %@",  error);
    [self removeBanner];
    if(!localBannerAdded){
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        localBannerButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        localBannerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0);
        [localBannerButton setTitle:@"DOWNLOAD MORE FREE GAMES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        localBannerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//[UIColor clearColor];
        [localBannerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
        [self.view addSubview:localBannerButton];

        [localBannerButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,(size.height-CGRectGetHeight(localBannerButton.frame)/2)-2)];

        // Add Target-Action Pair
        [localBannerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openAppStore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        localBannerAdded = YES;
    }
 }
```

Comment: My banner had 1 pixel distance from the game play area, so removing the banner from the game play screen, and asking for a new evaluation, fixed for me. The sad is it took almost 3 months to get an answer with the problem from Admob, I never got an email telling it, or any other contact from admob. Fixing was fast, after Apple approved the new version of my game, in 12 hours my banner was back.

Comment: Almost two years later I'm still having the same problem. Really time I switched to another advertising platform.

Comment: It working when app newly install on Simulator/ Devices.

Answer (score 30):

I just had this error today, the problem for me was simple, it was because the `adUnitID` is basically still new. I had to wait more than 2 hours after creating the `adUnitID` in order for the ads to be served.

If you have this error, and some of your `adUnitIDs` serve ads and some don't. You're highly likely having the same issue, and the only way to fix it is to wait.

Comment: I just integrated with AdMob for ios mobile application.  got app id and added configureWithApplicationID in appdelegate and initWithAdUnitID  in viewcontroller    request.testDevices = @[ @"some id"];  Here request.testdevices is not required?   after read your answer i will wait try to wait for 2 hours.

Comment: any followup? did you try after 2 hours

Comment: I'm waiting for 2 hours to pass since 2 weeks ago :). This doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

The ad server will return this message mainly because of the following:

- There are no ads for your ad unit id.
- Check whether your ad unit id is proper or not.
- You will get the same error if either your banner width/height is 0.
- Make sure that your adUnitID is perfect.

or
check following links  its may help you

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ioXU2nX9W28

[AdMob Legacy Publisher ID not showing ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150298/admob-legacy-publisher-id-not-showing-ads)

Comment: I don't believe I been blacklisted, I have looked on my adsense account and I don't see anything there on the status.
I sent a message so they can check if its blacklist, no response yet.
I tried both, no lucky, I guess I will have to wait so some one from admob looks to my account,  also I'm sure its not the size as it works if I change the bundle Identifier, and sure its not the adUnitID as it also show with different bundle.

Comment: Setting the banner width/height fixed it for me.  Hugely helpful!

Comment: My banner had 1 pixel distance from the game play area, so removing the banner from the game play screen, and asking for a new evaluation, fixed for me. The sad is it took almost 3 months to get an answer with the problem from Admob, I never got an email telling it, or any other contact from admob. Fixing was fast, after Apple approved the new version of my game, in 12 hours my banner was back.

Comment: This solved it for me, I had my banner height to 0 and if I receive an ad I put it to 50 but since it was 0, the delegate was always failing to get an ad.

Comment: @mrgrieves did you have to contact google ad mobs support to get the issue resolved? I am having a similar issue, although I am not sure who to contact.

Comment: No, I didn't have to contact support.  But that was in 2017, so things may have changed.

Answer (score 12):

I had just created a new account and seen that problem. When checking my account there was a message shown on the top of admob page: "Your ad units are not displaying ads because you haven't provided your account payments information yet.". Click on the button Fix it, fill the form and the ads will be shown within few hours

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are using the test ad IDs when in a debug session.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner?hl=en-US

> The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit ID for iOS banners: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716

Comment: Solved using this code!

Answer (score 5):

I met this error too. Both my banner and interstitial ads failed with this error. I found that it is my mistake to change UserAgent globally, after I change UserAgent to default it works well.

Comment: How to change UserAgent?

Comment: I ran into issues serving both live and test ads, and it turned out it was because I was registering a "@UserAgent" key with my app's defaults plist using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent":@"MyUserAgent"}];`.  Removing this key and setting UserAgent manually via `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and `WKWebViewConfiguration` where needed resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

This error could happen if you have not setup your payment and billing information in your AdMob account.
As per Admob after you setup the payment details, it can take up to 2 hours before it would be completely functional

[Billing and Payments](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772229?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

1. changing banner id to example id.
2. run the app then .
3. changing id back to production id.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the reason why it started showing this is that I didn't have any payment methods set up on my AdMob account.

Once I have set this up, the error has disappeared and ads started showing instantly.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: If payment method was not configured previously, then that is often the source of the problem.

Comment: After setting up the account how long does it take ads to show up ? @Dejan Atanasov?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using your app in debug or testing mode make sure you are using test AppID and BannerID provided by google admob which would be as:-

Google Test AdMobID:
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511

Google Test BannerID
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason is a **Constraint** bug.

> you should guarantee your bannerView's constraint to other views is
>   right

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when testing the sample application on my phone. I fixed with the following steps:

Reset Advertising identifier on iPhone 6, Go to:

> Settings -> Privacy -> Advertising -> Reset Ad identifier

Comment: I can not found the "Reset Ad identifier" can you please let me know where it will be.

Answer (score 3):

After create `adUnitID`, Wait for 1-2 hours and then try it out.

Because I had the same issue and it gets solved just after 1-2 hours.

Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, ads are working fine but suddenly it stop showing ad with error: *No ad to show*.
I noticed console is throwing error about test device identifier. Somehow the test device identifier get changed. I don't know how it happen, may be due to Xcode upgrade. I am not sure. But once I changed the test device identifier, it start working again.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make any modifications in code if this error pops, just wait about 3-4 days. Google takes time to send adds for new accounts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to make an other variable of GADBannerView. Use one variable in every controller by making it global and just change unit id.

e.g this line should be out of any controller (global)

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
```

then use it wherever you want and just change id accordingly

```
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-exampleid-abcabc938-4e8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was used to init the banner like this:

`adBannerView = GADBannerView()`

and it was working.

I can't say precisely from which AdMob library version, but suddently the banner wasn't show anymore.

Init the banner with the size as parameter, fixed the problem:

`adBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding `request.testDevice = @[@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"]` before load request.(I get this tip and test device number from console)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think should be used the test ad Ids from the integration guide from Google, after that change to your Ad Ids when it goes live.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this issue even with google test ad units.

In my scenario, problem was, I modified the WkWebView UserAgent directly without concatenating with the real one.

I had to change from;

```
static func arrangeUserAgent() {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in
        webView.customUserAgent = "Some Awesome User Agent"
        let dictionary = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("UserAgent", webView.customUserAgent!))
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dictionary)
    }
}
```

to;

```
static func arrangeUserAgent() {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in
        let mergedUserAgent = "\(result ?? "") Some Awesome UserAgent"
        webView.customUserAgent = mergedUserAgent
        let dictionary = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("UserAgent", mergedUserAgent))
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dictionary)
    }
}
```

Had rough times to find the problem.
Be careful with the UserAgent you change.

Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

In the Settings of your iOS device: Settings > Privacy > Advertising: Turn on and then turn off "Limit Ad Tracking" ("Reset of Ad Identifier" doesn't always help. Try "Reset of Ad Identifier" first and comment if this action doesn't help you). 
But! It will help only get ads on your own device and will not solve the problem that matching rate of your ad is low.